# server freezes after receiving two grpc messages from the client (python)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, grpc

i'm trying to write an asynchronous data transfer between server and client over grpc. The server freezes after receiving two grpc messages from the client...
Can you tell please  me what I'm doing wrong, please?

auth.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";


message CheckTokenRequest {
    string token = 1;
}


message AuthInfo {
    optional string user_id = 1;
    optional string role = 2;
    bool success = 3;
}


message CheckTokenResponse {
    repeated AuthInfo validations = 1;
}


service Auth {
    rpc Checker (CheckTokenRequest) returns (CheckTokenResponse);
}
```

client.py:

```
import asyncio
import grpc
from auth_pb2_grpc import AuthStub
import auth_pb2


async def get_token(token: str):
    async with grpc.aio.insecure_channel('127.0.0.1:50051') as channel:
        client = AuthStub(channel)
        request = auth_pb2.CheckTokenRequest(token=token)
        response = await client.Checker(request)
        print(response)

async def main():
    for i in range(100):
        lol = await get_token('1234')
        print(lol)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

server.py:

```
import asyncio
import datetime as dt
import json
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from logging import info
from grpc import aio
import grpc
import jwt

import auth_pb2
import auth_pb2_grpc

KEY = 'TOP_SECRET_KEY'
ALGORITHM = 'HS256'

class CheckerTokenService(
    auth_pb2_grpc.AuthServicer
):

    async def Checker(self, request, context):

        if not request.token:
            context.abort(grpc.StatusCode.NOT_FOUND, "token not found")

        print(request.token)

        # payload = self.is_valid(request.token)

        return auth_pb2.CheckTokenResponse(
            validations=[
                auth_pb2.AuthInfo(user_id=request.token, role=request.token, success=request.token)])

        #return auth_pb2.CheckTokenResponse(
        #     validations=[
        #         auth_pb2.AuthInfo(user_id=payload['user_id'], role=payload['role'], success=payload['success'])])


async def serve():

    server = grpc.aio.server(ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    auth_pb2_grpc.add_AuthServicer_to_server(CheckerTokenService(), server)

    server.add_insecure_port("127.0.0.1:50051")
    await server.start()
    await server.wait_for_termination()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(serve())
```

If you can show me how to fix the code to make it work - I will be grateful, as it will save me time!